# nested if statement in query

Tags: ms-access

(please excuse that I didn't use aliases).   I would like  my query output to say "none" if 3rd qrtr sales equals 4th quarter sales, but my output is just saying "up" when they equal each other. Please help me correct this code

```
trend: IIf([qryQuarterlyCustomersales3rdQuarter_final]
.[3rd qrtr sls]=[qryQuarterlyCustomersales4thQuarter_final]
.[4th qrtr sls],"none",
IIf([qryQuarterlyCustomersales3rdQuarter_final]
.[3rd qrtr sls]>[qryQuarterlyCustomersales4thQuarter_final]
.[4th qrtr sls],"down","up"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the two values are exactly the same?
As written there appears to be a slight mistake in the inner `iif` statement, but that doesn't explain the results you're currently getting.

Pseudocode helps me understand how these expressions work:

```
if q3 = q4
    "none"
else*
    if q3 > q4
        "up"
    else*
        "down"
```

*note that `else` is implied; not legal syntax here

Making as few changes as possible, this should work as you expect it to:

```
trend: IIf([qryQuarterlyCustomersales3rdQuarter_final]
.[3rd qrtr sls] = [qryQuarterlyCustomersales4thQuarter_final]
.[4th qrtr sls],"none",
IIf([qryQuarterlyCustomersales3rdQuarter_final]
.[3rd qrtr sls] > [qryQuarterlyCustomersales4thQuarter_final]
.[4th qrtr sls],"up","down")) # <- these final two args should be switched
```

[Documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/iif-function-HA001228853.aspx):

> Syntax
>
> IIf(expr, truepart, falsepart)
>
> The IIf function syntax has these
>   arguments:
>
> ARGUMENT  DESCRIPTION expr    Required.
>   Expression you want to evaluate.
>   truepart  Required. Value or expression
>   returned if expr is True.
>   falsepart Required. Value or
>   expression returned if expr is False.

Answer (score 1):

What data type is [3rd qrtr sls] and [4th qrtr sls]?
can you post some sample data?

what does this yield?

```
IIF([qryQuarterlyCustomersales4thQuarter_final]
.[4th qrtr sls] > [qryQuarterlyCustomersales3rdQuarter_final]
.[3rd qrtr sls], "up", IIF([qryQuarterlyCustomersales4thQuarter_final].[4th qrtr sls] <[qryQuarterlyCustomersales3rdQuarter_final]
.[3rd qrtr sls], "down", "none"))
```

if this still yields "up", then you know the values stored in those two columns aren't equal